# Python code not working when virtual environment is active but works when it is deactivated

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, virtualenv, python-venv

I am using code that relies on the opencv library, the code is cloned from the following repo if someone wishes to reproduce this problem fully: 
 https://github.com/kmhmubin/Face-Recognition-Attendance-System 
 but the exact snippet that I was struggling with is here:

```
# ----------- train images function ---------------
def TrainImages():
    recognizer = cv2.face_LBPHFaceRecognizer.create()
    # rest of the code...
```

And this code was giving me a "cv2 attribute not found: face" error when the virtual environment was active but when I deactivated it the code worked properly, why is that exactly? Am I not supposed to run the code when the venv is active or is there something wrong with my venv setup? 
 
 For the venv setup I followed the exact same steps in the above repo and tried running the code while it was still active, is this incorrect? I tried to check if this is a version issue but the problem is that when I tried to install the 4.0.1 opencv contrib version to the venv it didn't recognize it as a valid version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably did a "pip install" without activating your virtualenv

Comment: Yeah, that probably was it, I uninstalled the project and reinstalled everything inside the venv. Now it doesn't show the error anymore, maybe I missed something on the first install. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When you downloaded the package and created your virtual environment did you install the necessary packages specified on the `README.md` file?

- `pip install opencv-contrib-python`
- `pip install numpy`
- `pip install pandas`
- `pip install Pillow`
- `pip install pytest-shutil`
- `pip install python-csv`
- `pip install yagmail`

Also, keep in mind the README.me file says this package was written in `Python 3.7` however, the `print()` functions  in `main.py` suggests this is `Python2` This could have caused an error as well.

Comment: It turns out I just needed to re-install everything all over again, thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Any package that has been installed in virtual environment will only work for that virtual environment when it is activated.
When we deactivate it , it will work for the packages that are installed by you on your machine without that particular virtual environment.